# A first order linear inhomogenous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider this ODE without any initial conditions.

$$ax'(t) + bx(t) + c = 0$$ where $a,b,c$ is a nonzero constant.

What method could be used to solve this ODE? I am seeking a technique that does not require differentiating both sides and turning it into a second-order ODE.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are constants?

Comment: Yes they are. I will edit; thank you for answering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

The equation is separable, so you can separate and integrate.

You can also use integrating factor or the Laplace Transform.

Comment: Oh I guess it is...didn't see the obvious